# How to use the odradek to hide?

Tags: death-stranding

I recently received an Odradek upgrade that is supposed to let you generate a holographic structure in which you can hide.  I got busy doing other missions and forgot about it, and now can't remember what it said about how to use that feature.

How do you create a holographic structure with the Odradek?

Comment: As I recall, the game never quite explained it. I'm actually curious myself how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found how to do it (by pure coincidence).

The Hologram Generator is hidden behind the D-pad Up equipment wheel. Simply keep the D-pad Up button pressed, select the Hologram Generator with your right analog stick, and press [image: Cross button].

If you don't see the Hologram Generator, you might need to press R3 (click on the right analog stick) to change page.